# Where is the program for handling interrupts i.e. interrupt handler stored?

Tags: cpu-architecture

So I am studying computer organization and I came across this term interrupt handler .Do we have to install this program and where is it stored ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Interrupt handlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) are stored in memory, like all executable code has to be.

In a full multi-tasking OS, it's in the kernel.

Under something like DOS, programs could ["terminate and stay resident"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_and_stay_resident_program), leaving their interrupt handlers hooked into the interrupt table.  Multi-tasking OSes provide interfaces for programs to run in the background, and of course can't let un-trusted programs [hook interrupts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057157/what-does-interrupt-hooking-mean).